# Count amount separately depends on field value in Crystal Report VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am a beginner for Crystal report. I do not know how to work with formula editor.
My question is,

Table Name - Expenses

Field Name - Date, Purpose(Text), Less(Boolean), Amount(Double)

I want to count Less(Yes) Amount separately and Less(No) Amount separately. How to count this.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You will need two formulas:

Formula will show 1 for each record that has Less = True:

```
if less = True then 1
else 0
```

Formula 2 will show 1 for each record that has Less = False:

```
if less = False then 1
else 0
```

Now put those two formulas in your detail section and then do a sum on each one in your group footer. You can suppress the formulas in the detail section if you don't want to see them.

Hope that helps,

Chris